# substract commission total balance after order place woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress

Single product page I have the option to add a commission where the user inputs some commission which is added to the product price mean product price + commission = subtotal and shows the cart page and checkout page. But I want when the user clicks the place order button to place the order, the product commission that is there at that time to be excluded.

It means when the user clicks the place order button, the order will be placed with the product original price excluding the commission and when the user makes the payment from Terawallet it will also be the product original price. There will be no commission in the order and the user will not pay commission except the original price.

There are the hooks but these hooks are not working. What can I try next?

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'deduct_commission_from_terawallet_balance');

function deduct_commission_from_terawallet_balance($order_id) {
    // Get the order object
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    // Check if the payment method is Terawallet
    if ($order->get_payment_method() == 'terawallet') {
        // Get the commission amount
        $commission = 0;
        foreach ($order->get_items() as $item) {
            $commission += $item->get_meta('commission');
        }

        // Get the user ID
        $user_id = $order->get_user_id();

        // Get the current Terawallet balance
        $balance = get_user_meta($user_id, 'terawallet_balance', true);

        // Deduct the commission from the balance
        $new_balance = $balance - $commission;

        // Update the Terawallet balance
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'terawallet_balance', $new_balance);
    }
}
```

By looking at the image, you will understand that commission + product price = subtotal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkRIQ.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sy2bF.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqrXp.png)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.